# In Laravel, how to depedency inject service into controller method

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, service-provider

Sorry for newbie question, but I cant find any example on how to actually use Service Providers (Laravel documentation shows only how to create them).

Since Laravel's paginator doesn't work with grouping, I want to create my own paginator service, but I dont know how to inject said service into controller. Forum controller throws me exception: `Class App\Http\Controllers\CustomPaginator does not exist`, but I thought that if I bind service class to service container, it can be resolved using custom name?

Here are the files:

**app/Http/Controllers/For**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ForumModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Forum extends Controller
{
    public function index($page = 1, CustomPaginator $paginator)
    {
        $topics = ForumModel::orderBy("sticky", "DESC")->orderBy("lastpost", "DESC");

        return view("forum", ["topics" => $topics]);
    }
}
```

**app/Providers/CustomPaginatorServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CustomPaginatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind("CustomPaginator", CustomPaginatorServiceProvider::class);
    }

    public function a()
    {
        echo "It works!";
    }
}
```

**Providers table in app config**

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Package Service Providers...
     */
    Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider::class,

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */
    App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
    App\Providers\CustomPaginatorServiceProvider::class

],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't bind **CustomPaginatorServiceProvider** inside **CustomPaginatorServiceProvider**

and bind an instance.

```
$this->app->bind('CustomPaginator', function () {
    return new Services\CustomPaginator();
});
```

1. create *service provider* **CustomPaginatorServiceProvider**
2. register *service provider* **CustomPaginatorServiceProvider** in app config
3. create *service* **CustomPaginator**
4. bind *service* **CustomPaginator** in **CustomPaginatorServiceProvider**

btw You can bind *service* **CustomPaginator** in **AppServiceProvider** instead of creating new *service provider*

---

config/app.php in alias array:

```
...
'CustomPaginator' => \App\Services\CustomPaginator::class,
...
```

inside controller action:

```
public function someAction(\CustomPaginator $paginator)
{
    dd($paginator);
}
```

And if you need to pass some data into CustomPaginator method __construct - just write this in ServiceProvider:

```
$this->app->bind(\App\Services\CustomPaginator::class, function () {
    return new \App\Services\CustomPaginator($firstParam, $secondParam, ...);
});
```

Comment: After reading the documentation I was pretty sure that services are just methods of ServiceProvider class. Especially since there isn't a single word on how to create services, Is there any convention, or can I just smash any class I want into the provider?

Comment: @Yotsuya I store them in _app\Services_ )

Comment: Okay, so this is exactly what I did, I removed `CustomPaginatorServiceProvider` and bound my CustomPaginator in the `AppServiceProvider`. Now when I call it from `app()` helper, it works as intended (i use `app()->make("CustomPaginator")`; However, trying depedency injection with bound name throws me error `Class App\Http\Controllers\CustomPaginator does not exist`. What do I need to do so the service can be injected into my controller method?

Comment: Wish I could upvote you more. I also leared that I could achieve what I wanted by contracts, but the method you proposed works too. Thanks a lot!